# Search all child nodes of XML node for a value and remove the grandparent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Trying to use

```
exportDoc.Root.Elements("string").Where(node => !(node.Element("product").HasElements) || node.Element("product").Element("type").Value != product).Remove();
```

to remove the nodes in my XML document where the `product` string I'm searching for doesn't occur. Here is a sample of my XML structure:

```
<root>
   <string id = "Hithere">
      <product>
         <type>orange</type>
         <type>yellow</type>
         <type>green</type>
      <product>
      <element2/>
      <element3/>
    </string>
    <string id ="...">
     ...
     ... 
</root>
```

So I need to look under the `product` element of each `string` element AND at each of the `type` elements therein to see if the value of string `product` (input to the method where this is contained) occurs. At present, it looks like my code only removes the node if the `product` string I'm searching for matches the value of just the first `type` element.

The whole point is to remove all string nodes from this xdoc that don't have the product I'm looking for listed under their `product` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your search condition slightly:

```
var nodesToRemove = xDoc.Root
    .Elements("string")
    .Where(node =>
        !(node.Element("product").HasElements) ||
        node.Element("product").Elements("type").All(x => x.Value != product))
    .ToList();
```

This should match elements which **all** string:product:types differ from `product` value (or in other words - if at least one `<type>` will match your `product`, it won't be marked for removal).

Answer (score 1):

You can't Remove() while you're still enumerating (deferred execution).

You need something more like:

```
// untested
var toRemove = exportDoc.Root.Elements("string")
    .Where(node => !(node.Element("product").HasElements) ||
           node.Element("product").Element("type").Value != product).ToList();
toRemove.Remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think the problem is that `.Element("type")` only returns the first `type` element. So, if there is only one product type there, it works, but if there are multiple product types, specifically ones that occur before it in the XML, then it won't work.